# IfError, leave formula in place/don't do anything?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet, where I'd like to drag down a particular index/match formula, but where the formula does not return a value, I'd like it to keep the formula that is already in place (which sums up a few of the items below it).

I know that you could just use the cell reference for the if_error part of the formula, but this would return the value of the cell as it is now, and wouldn't use the current formula to generate a new value based on the values returned by the index match formula.

I have attached pictures below. Basically, I want to leave the sum formulas as is, but just be able to drag down that first index formula (the actual spreadsheet I'm dealing with has many different spaces, and is very long, otherwise I'd just copy the formula manually).

If this isn't possible, are there any other solutions? Another thing I tried was for each index/match that didn't return a value, I had it return the formula as a string, and then I'd copy/paste special with values, replace the column in the formula that is a string to the column I'm looking for, and then it would evaluate the formula that was, before, a string. But then you lose the formulas for all the other cells.

So the issue is that some cells are used to sum, and I don't want to drag the formula over those cells, but at the same time, I do need to use the formula over the whole range, otherwise it would just take too long.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Why is this about VBA or Excel-VBA? It seems to be an Excel-Formula based question. '*I'd like to drag down a particular index/match formula...*'

Answer (score 1):

Once you put a formula in G1, the previous formula in that cell is no longer available, so referencing G1 in your new formula would just produce a circular reference.

Instead think of a formula that combines both formulas into one: it should detect in which situation it is and then perform the appropriate calculation.

In your case, I think this formula will do what you want:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($M$3:$M$9, MATCH(F1,$L$3:$L$9)), IF(E1="", "", SUM(G2:G4)))
```

Put it in cell G1 and copy it down.

Note how it looks at column E to decide whether it should do the sum. I also adapted a bit the part you already had, by making some references absolute (adding some `$`), because the area in the L and M columns is positioned at fixed rows.

Comment: Thanks for this, I appreciate it! A complication I neglected to mention is that the sum function, in the case where the index does not return a value, is different each time (i.e. it sums up different things), so that part of the formula would need to change each time. However, I do have another column in the spreadsheet which does the same calculation for the same number of rows, in another column. I'm thinking now whether I could somehow use use that formula in my new column, but just change the column each time?

Comment: If you have that calculation done in another cell then instead of the `SUM(G2:G4)`, put the reference to that cell, like `P1`, or whatever column it is.

Answer (score 0):

Add a helper column in row H for your Index-Match formula and copy it all the way down. Then, in row I do an if statement. If row H meets the criteria you want, do that, else use row G.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I found a good solution, especially in the case where you are going to be using the spreadsheet over and over, and the format won't change much. This might be too specific for anyone to use, but posting it just in case someone gets some use out of it.

First I created two macros, one to hide the sum rows, and another to unhide all the sum rows. I got the sum rows from another column by copying all the formulas across to the new column I'm looking at. Numbers will of course be wrong, but the sum formulas will be what we want to keep. You can speed this up by finding "sum" in formulas and then selecting all of the results.

Next, use the macro which hides all the sum rows.

Next, create the index formula in the first row. Control shift down to select all rows beneath. Then, "find", and "go to special" and select "only visible cells", and then hit F2, and control enter, and this will copy the formula down to all the visible cells, ie the non-sum cells.

Then use your unhide macro, and it should be golden!

You can use this technique for any spreadsheet where the source data format is different from target, and where you have fixed formulas in the target which you always will need.